# How to implement autocomplete for multiple textfield on certain number of text length

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autocomplete

There is many library available for this case, but my scenario is a bit different. I have a ViewController having three textfields. I have to implement autocomplete for every textfields, and show the suggestion below the textfield. For all the datasource of textfield,I am dependent on the web-service. The problem is its working only for one textfield. Please suggest some effecient way to do this.
1)Suggestions should be shown below or above the textfield, after entering two characters. UI shouldn't be blocked, user can continue typing.(I am making call on the server with two character on background thread, and receive the response to show as suggestions. Filter logic is implemented on the server)
2) If user doesn't select anything from the suggestion, textfield data will be send to the server.
3) Anywhere tap on the screen should hide the suggestion.(The problem is, if I use tap gesture recognizer, tableview cell also doesn't get touch)

**creating tableview to show suggestions**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];    
self.orderNoTextField.delegate = self;
self.empNameTextField.delegate = self;
self.custNameTextField.delegate = self;

rectForEmp = CGRectMake(0, self.empNameTextField.frame.origin.y + self.empNameTextField.frame.size.height, self.empNameTextField.frame.size.width, 120);

rectForCust = CGRectMake(0, self.orderNoTextField.frame.origin.y, self.custNameTextField.frame.size.width, 120);

autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:rectForCust style:UITableViewStylePlain];
autocompleteTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
autocompleteTableView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;


autocompEmpTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:rectForEmp style:UITableViewStylePlain];
autocompEmpTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
autocompEmpTableView.delegate = self;
autocompEmpTableView.dataSource = self;
autocompEmpTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
autocompEmpTableView.hidden = YES;
autocompEmpTableView.canCancelContentTouches = NO; 
[self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
[self.view addSubview:autocompEmpTableView];
}
```

**fetching suggestions**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

if (self.custNameTextField.text.length == 2)
{
    autocompEmpTableView.hidden = YES;

    [self generateDataForCustomerName];

}
else if (self.empNameTextField.text.length == 2)
{
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;

    [self generateDataForEmployeeName];

}
   return YES;
}
- (void)generateDataForCustomerName
{

/** get background thread for datasource of autocomplete **/


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    {
        httpClient = [[KKHttpClient alloc]init];
        //httpClient.responseDelegate = self;
        //NSString *params = [self.empNameTextField text];

        params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"rqBody\":{\"searchKey\":\"%@\"}}",[self.custNameTextField text]];

        relativeUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"auth/getcustomernamelist"];
        [httpClient connectWithUrl:relativeUrl withData:params completion:^(NSMutableDictionary *responseJson)
         {
             NSLog(@"response check for new methods:%@", responseJson);

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                 //Here returns to main thread to update the UI.

                 /** initialize the array and add object to it**/

                 custNameData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                 custNameData = [responseJson[@"rsBody"]valueForKey:@"msg"];

                 autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
                 [autocompleteTableView reloadData];

             });


         }];

    }

});
}
```

**Tableview to show suggesyions**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
if(tableView == autocompleteTableView)
{
    return empNameData.count;
}
else
{
    return custNameData.count;
}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == autocompEmpTableView) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompEmpRowIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];

    }
    employeeName = [[empNameData valueForKey:@"employeeName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    employeeId = [[empNameData valueForKey:@"employeeId"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *autoCompleteText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@%@%@", employeeName, @"(", employeeId, @")"];

    cell.textLabel.text = autoCompleteText;

    return cell;

}
else
{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];

}


    customerName = [[custNameData valueForKey:@"customerName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    customerCode = [[custNameData valueForKey:@"customerCode"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *autoCompleteText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@%@", customerName, @"(", customerCode, @")"];

    cell.textLabel.text = autoCompleteText;

return cell;
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *title = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

if(tableView == autocompEmpTableView)
{
    self.empNameTextField.text = title;
    autocompEmpTableView.hidden = YES;
}
else{
    self.custNameTextField.text = title;
    autocompleteTableView.hidden =YES;
}
    }
```